# Node-Webkit MenuItem click function issue

Tags: node-webkit

I have an issue with my Node-Webkit MenuItem click function which I believe I have narrowed down to changing the URL from within the Javascript on my loading page.  I have a 5 second timer which changes the page when complete.  If I set the document location to a web page on a web server (could be anything even www.google.com) from within the javascript in my loading.html page, my MenuItem Click functions do not work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.location = "http://localhost:8080/myapp/index.htm";
}, 5000);
});
```

If I change the document location to a html page which is contained within my app.nw package, my MenuItem click functions work and the page will change to any of my

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp pages

$(document).ready(function() {
window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.location = "test.html";
}, 5000);
});
```

Here is my Node-Webkit javascript file contained within the app.nw package which places a menu bar on the application window.

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var win = gui.Window.get();

var rootMenu = new gui.Menu({ type: 'menubar'});
var sysMenu = new gui.Menu();

sysMenu.append(new gui.MenuItem({
type: 'normal',
label: 'Google',
click: function (){
    Window.window.location.assign("http://localhost:8080/myapp/customers.htm");
} 
}));

gui.Window.get().menu = rootMenu;
```

Has anyone else come across this or am I doing something the wrong way?

Thanks